# How to apply plaster to a plaster damaged drywall section

Tags: drywall, plaster

Some plaster came off our drywall.  It's not a huge area but bigger than I'd like to use a polyfiller on.

Can I plaster directly onto the area or do I need to use a PVA or similar?  Is there a technique to get it flush with the rest of the wall?

[image: damaged section]

Comment: It’s hard to tell from your picture what you have there.   It doesn’t look like drywall to me.  My best guess is one or two layers of paint on top, then the brown stuff is wallpaper glue residue, and underneath that is the original layer of paint over plaster.  OTOH that edge on the left looks like it could be the edge of a drywall sheet. Can you definitely confirm any of these layers is paper?  (Might be wallpaper or lining paper or drywall facing .... let's start with yes paper or no paper?)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, plaster and drywall are two very different things.  Please use the correct terms.

It appears from the photo that you have damaged drywall, that looks like it may have been improperly patched in the past.  While you could try to fix this using drywall compound, that will be a very difficult thing to make it stick and look good over such a large area.

The usual way to fix something like this is to REMOVE a section of the drywall, fit a new piece of drywall in the void, and then use drywall tape and drywall compound to blend the edges into the existing wall surface.

Comment: TBH, it appears to me that, where it's flaked away all the way to the deepest level, that there is plaster there, not drywall paper. The little pock marks that I see look like places in my house where I've had to do some plaster & lath repair. It's hard to tell from this one photo, though, and a focused, sharp close up of some of that section would be much more telling. Under the assumption that this is drywall, however, I'd agree with your answer 100%.

Comment: By drywall I mean plasterboard https://mybuildingsupplies.ie/product/plaster-slab-plain-8x4x12?gclid=CjwKCAjwgZuDBhBTEiwAXNofRKCp4s80CMcFwy8PKPHBfFineOeJOvQRRaD2bkhIDsJqlhu9AURzBBoCpMoQAvD_BwE it has been plastered over as is fairly standard I believe?

Comment: Here in the USA that is called "drywall".  But whether it's drywall or plasterboard, it's not "plaster" which is a different product which is applied to a backer, usually called lath.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are in the UK, or somewhere where veneer plaster is the standard wall because you referenced PolyFilla.

I can't really see if the broken layers are paint, but I'm guessing they are because veneer plaster is very hard and doesn't break when you have a paint adhesion failure. Assuming I am correct, that is just paint that is broken, I'd use an all purpose joint compound to fill the area so it is flush, then I'd sand it smooth, and feather in new paint.  Joint compound has adhesive properties, so no additional bonding agent is necessary.

If you did need to do more actual plastering, then a bonding agent is necessary, but I don't think the break went deep enough.